# Jenkins CI with Unity on local machine

Tags: unity

I have seen some people using Jenkins CI with Unity, would it be wise to install Jenkins locally and use it with Unity? I've never used Jenkins, so I can't imagine why not. Is this ill-advised?

I would have set up Jenkins on my old laptop, but I don't have windows on it. Is there any harm in using it locally?

Comment: I think it will depend on the application requirement

Comment: Could you tell what you want to build.

Comment: there is also this : https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/katana if you're interested.

Answer (score 1):

Jenkins CI does come with the disk I/O, memory, and CPU overhead inherent in running a Java + Apache Tomcat service continuously while your computer is running, otherwise there are no other realistic consequences.

The question is, if you've never used Jenkins CI, why do you want to integrate it with Unity? Unless you discover a good reason that outweighs the costs of adding a new technology to your project/toolchain, don't. So the question "would it be wise" and "is this ill-advised?" depends widely on your project's requirements and even then falls upon personal opinion.

Comment: Is there a better suited CI for use with Unity?

Answer (score 0):

There is no harm using Jenkins on your local machine. Since a CI system is intended to run builds automatically (e.g. nightly builds with tests to ensure code integrity) it would be better to have it running on another machine.

Jenkins can be used on different operating systems as can be seen in the download section on the Jenkins website (https://jenkins-ci.org/).